# What is default settings to reffer to file location in xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, project, location

What is default settings to reffer to file location in xcode project ?

i have doubts between them

1. relative to build project
2. relative to project
3. relative to enclosing group
4. relative to source path
5. Absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be well documented.  As I read "How Files are Referenced" in the "Xcode Project Management Guide":

1. If the file is in the project's folder, you get a reference relative to an enclosing group.
2. If the file is created by one of the targets, you get a reference relative to the build product.
3. Otherwise, I think, you get an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

By default - Eclosing-Group*.

*[Beginning Xcode (James Bucanek) Chapter 5, p.76](http://books.google.ru/books?id=rYjv9MKZ3JwC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=If%20the%20file%20is%20in%20the%20project%27s%20folder,%20you%20get%20a%20reference%20relative%20to%20an%20enclosing%20group%20xcode&source=bl&ots=og_YxT6hv6&sig=iZ1YGHbW9irQu5WDK0NvyirE5Jc&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=wGyIU8qPOvPS4QSsvICwAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=If%20the%20file%20is%20in%20the%20project%27s%20folder,%20you%20get%20a%20reference%20relative%20to%20an%20enclosing%20group%20xcode&f=false)