# File Links to Old Folder in Project Navigator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two PLIST files, one is for target free version, another one is for target paid version. Recently I copied the whole project files to another folder, but when I right click on the paid.plist file in Project Navigator, and select **"Show in Finder"**, it still link to the paid.plist file in old folder. The other files seems to be fine without this issue.

What's wrong? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your plist files were added not relative to the group folder. Perhaps this was set for absolute path?

[image]

Comment: I think you are right, do you know why that file would be added by absolute path? Other files are fine.

Comment: This answer sums it up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271971/what-is-default-settings-to-reffer-to-file-location-in-xcode-project